# Looking for SIMPLE persistent store for Java

Tags: java, persistence

Is there truly no SIMPLE, persistent, embedded solution for Java?

I'm used to (from several years ago) bdb for Python: Dirt-simple, persistent disk hashes. Yet trying to find the same thing now for Java throws up nothing but noise! I get:

1. bdb je (from Oracle)--even discounting the fact that it's from Oracle, this is still much more complex than what I remember!
2. H2/Derby/HSQLDB--require all the overhead of SQL for very simple stores!
3. JDBM3 etc.--still not mature...

I could go on...

Surely there must be a simple, persistent, embedded, mature solution.

Comment: Does http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/  help?

Comment: Suggest taking a look at this [question and answers][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451935/suggest-a-simple-nosql-database-for-java-project

Comment: @user890204 Rather than describing your perceived technical need, you would likely get more and better answers if you described the problem.

Comment: @Jayan pcollections looks pretty neat, but their definition of "persistent" is what I (a Scala user) call "functional" or "immutable"--I'm looking for a solution that persists across invocations of the JVM.

Comment: @exabrial: What I'm looking for is (at it's simplest) an implementation of a Map that stores data to disk rather than to memory, and does so with as few bells and whistles as possible. bdb would be fine if they hadn't added bells and whistles (+ it's now owned by Oracle :-( )

Comment: @user890204 You restated your requirements without telling us what you are trying to do... Are you trying to write kittens to a disk? What is your use case?

Answer (score 3):

Why not JDBM2? It is mature and similar to JDBM3

http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/

Comment: I simply hadn't come across jdbm2 in my google searches. Will look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[JSimpleDB](https://code.google.com/p/jsimpledb/) is a new Java persistence layer that runs on top of any key/value store and provides a relatively simple, Java-centric view. It's not mature yet but addresses your other criteria.

JSimpleDB provides relatively complete persistence layer (transactions, Spring integration, etc.). If all you want is to store a map, there are simpler answers out there.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this project.

Answer (score 1):

H2 MVStore is real simple to use, it's like a map.

http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html

I just tried it out a bit in scala using an arbitrary nested data structure:

http://scastie.org/6110

Answer (score 1):

[MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) is available now and is stable. It is essentially a set of Java collections backed by disk storage. This is a successor to JDBM2 and JDBM3.